# Bad HTTP Location: header with nginx proxying couchdb

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, curl, couchdb

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for CouchDB.  I'd like to use a prefix for the proxy, e.g. `http://[ip]:8080/proxy/testdb` -> `http://localhost:5984/testdb`.  I'm getting `Location:` headers in the HTTP response which are causing my HTTP client to redirect and break.  How can I fix my nginx config?

My nginx server block looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /var/www/proxy;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  location /proxy {
    rewrite /proxy/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5984;
    proxy_redirect off;
#    proxy_set_header Host $host;
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Example HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 01:09:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 74
Connection: close
Location: http://192.168.0.100/testdb/2134922387
ETag: "1-f355543f12ede9fdc421b4c3ca06c1eb"
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Based on this, the HTTP client tries to redirect to `http://192.168.0.100/testdb/2134922387`, which gives a 404 error.  (Uncommenting the two commented config lines didn't seem to change anything).

Example command to produce these headers:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"_id\":\"2134922387\",\"test\":\"good\"}" http://192.198.0.100:8080/proxy/testdb
```

Any ideas on how to fix this `Location:` issue?

Edited to add: it looks like changing the `proxy_redirect` to `proxy_redirect http://$host/ /proxy/;` is helping.